# Showing label if greater than percentage using Arcade with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, arcade

I have a text field called PerVax1 that has percentages.

[image]

I want to create an expression that labels the features when the field has a percentage greater than 30%. Here's some things I've tried so far:

```js
var percentage = $feature.PerVax1;
var prcnt = "30%";
IIf(percentage >= "30%"){
return percentage}

//resulted in error:
Invalid expression.
Error on line 4.
Semicolon or new line expected.
```

```js
var precentage;
percentage = IIf($feature.PerVax1 >= "30%")
return percentage;

//resulted in error:
Invalid expression.
Error on line 2.
Wrong number of arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically had it already.

```js
var pct = $feature.PerVax1;
IIf(pct > "30%", $feature.PerVax1, "");
```

I forgot to mention I'm working in the label expression window.

[image]